# Li-ion portable car battery charger that can charge 12v batteries (e.g. car batteries, but not just jump-starting cars), available in UK

Tags: power-supply

There are hundreds of "portable jump starters", lithium ion battery packs with crocodile clip attachments that can be used to jump start a car. Many can also charge laptops or USB devices, or having a built-in light. Here are a few random examples: [1](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Compact-Portable-Advanced-Protection-Flashlight/dp/B011U6Q0K6/ref=pd_sim_sbs_263_13?ie=UTF8&dpID=51jIu7Le7wL&dpSrc=sims&preST=_AC_UL160_SR160%2C160_&refRID=C1WRJAA76CRRJKAEK0J0) [2](https://www.amazon.co.uk/VicTop-13600mAh-Portable-Rechargeable-Flashlight/dp/B01AK041QI/ref=sr_1_13?s=automotive&ie=UTF8&qid=1462540522&sr=1-13&keywords=portable%20car%20battery%20charger) [3](https://www.amazon.co.uk/DBPOWER-8000mAh-Portable-Starter-Battery/dp/B013UBRZKS/ref=sr_1_4?s=automotive&ie=UTF8&qid=1462540522&sr=1-4&keywords=portable%20car%20battery%20charger) [4](https://www.amazon.co.uk/ccbetter-Emergency-Suitable-Flashlight-Portable/dp/B011NC28VW/ref=pd_vtph_23_tr_t_2?ie=UTF8&refRID=2QKMQRWY9SWQNYEPV09P).

My problem with these, and jump-starting in general, is that it's not much use if your car has some problem *other* than the battery being flat causing it to not start, and then the car battery goes flat while you're trying to diagnose that problem. I'd like something portable that can be used to *recharge* a 12 volt battery, as well as jump start if that's possible.

I recently had exactly this problem. I used a solar panel to recharge the battery, but that's quite slow and cumbersome.

There's one device I've seen which seems to have the feature I want:

> ### [Stanley P2G7S Simple Start Lithium Battery Booster](http://www.stanleytools.com/products/automotive-tools/other-tools/power-station/simple-start-lithium-ion-battery-booster/p2g7s)
>
> When your battery is dead, just plug the booster into the 12-volt DC outlet or clamp it to the battery and the booster will start charging immediately and get you back on the road quickly.

...but unfortunately it seems to be only available in the USA.

---

So to be clear about the features I'm looking for, in priority order:

- **Essential:** Be able to *charge* a 12v car battery from flat to capable of starting in something like 5-30 minutes, even if there's some other problem preventing the car from starting.
- **Essential:** Be a portable, small, lightweight item chargable from a normal power supply
- **Essential:** Be available in the UK
- Desirable: Be able to jump-start a car
- Desirable: Be able to charge other devices (USB, 12v, 15v, 19v laptops)
- Desirable: Be able to charge a car battery using both direct crocodile clips and accessory socket attachments
- Desirable: Cost less than £100 (about $150 USD)
- Desirable: Have a built-in bright torch
- Desirable: Waterproof or splash-proof

Note: I said lithium ion in the title to give a general indication of the broad type of battery pack. I'm not too fussy about the exact chemistry, something similar like li-po (lithium polymer) would be fine (basically, not something like a bulky, heavy 5kg lead-acid type).

Comment: While this is an excellent and well-specified question, it also doesn't fit our site scope as defined in [What is Hardware?](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/265/what-is-hardware) - namely, what is effectively a battery can only perform one meaningful task, and doesn't need to connect to a computer to operate.

Comment: There are literally hundreds of questions on things that don't need to connect to computers... And I'm asking for something that performs four tasks (charging, jump starting, USB out, DC out)

Comment: You may be able to talk to the people in [Mechanics Stack Exchange Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop); they don't do recommendation questions on the site, but their chat might be able to help you.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I am in an identical position, and would be grateful for your advice.

Comment: No, nothing specific @Mawg in the end I figured out my car battery had a fault another way and replaced it

Comment: It would still be a useful thing to have around. My battery is very difficult to access, so I would rather take the starter/charger to it. [This](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00IDCMLFE/) and the very similar, but 25% cheaper [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B001C85UG8/) Look identical but rebranded, hence the price difference.  They seem ideal, but have an incredibly worrying 5 start to 1 start review ratio, so I am reluctant. I will continue to search fro "jump start" devices, rather than "battery chargers"